# php mysql search only give 1 result

Tags: php, mysql, search

I coded a search function but I always get only 1 result!

Does anyone know where the problem is?

```
<?PHP
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
      $sqlCmdSearch="SELECT * FROM name.name WHERE title LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['search'])."%'";
      $getSearch=mysql_query($sqlCmdSearch,$sqlHp);
          while($getSearch = mysql_fetch_array($getSearch)) {
    echo'<div id="main_item2">';
    echo'   <div class="main_image">';
    echo'   <a href="index.php?s=items&id='.$getSearch["id"].'"><img src="www/img/thumbs/'.$getSearch["image"].'"></a>';
    echo'   </div>';
    echo'   <div class="title_list">';
    echo'   <a href="index.php?s=items&id='.$getSearch["id"].'">'.$getSearch["title"].'</a>';
    echo'   </div>';
    echo'   <div class="description_list"> ';
    echo'   <p>'.$getSearch["description"].'</p>';
    echo'   </div>';
    echo'   <div class="button_list">';
    echo'   <p>Price: '.$getSearch["item_price"] .' '.$getSearch["currency"].'</p>';
    echo'   <span style="padding-left:15px;"><a href="index.php?s=items&id='.$getSearch["id"].'" class="button">Watch Item</a></span>';
    echo'   </div>';
    echo'</div>';
}
}
else{
echo '<p>Search failed please try again.</p>';
}
?>
```

Ive already tried everything but nothing helped..

Comment: Are you sure there is not just one matching result?

Comment: `mysql_*` methods are deprecated, you should use `mysqli_*` methods instead.

Comment: You are _overwriting_ `$getSearch`.  Use a different variable to assign the result of `mysql_fetch_array()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are overwriting your mysql results variable,

So replace your following code:

```
$getSearch=mysql_query($sqlCmdSearch,$sqlHp);
      while($getSearch = mysql_fetch_array($getSearch)) {
```

for this one:

```
$getSearch_set=mysql_query($sqlCmdSearch,$sqlHp);
      while($getSearch = mysql_fetch_array($getSearch_set)) {
```